# How to assign samples to key groups with Akai S2800i

Tags: hardware, sampler

I just picked up an Akai S2800i, but cannot find the manual for it (or S3000) online. I'm hoping that someone can direct me on how to assign samples to key groups in the Akai S3000. Thanks.